# hibernate: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm using hibernate-core in a maven project and I want to create the entities for the following database: [db_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9nv.png)

I'm just starting to learn hibernate, so please bear with me on this one. I know that it might be a stupid mistake but I just can't figure it out.

I'm getting the following exception when I try to test the code:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: entity.User.groups[entity.IsIn]

I will list the code for my entities below

**User**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private int userId;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<IsIn> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "customerName", nullable = false)
    private String customerName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private boolean is_active;

    @Column(name = "notificationType", nullable = false)
    private String notificationType;

    @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
    private String create_date;

    public User() { }

    public User(String customerName, String password, String email, boolean is_active, String notificationType, String create_date) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.is_active = is_active;
        this.notificationType = notificationType;
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }

    public void addGroup(Group group) {
        IsIn isIn = new IsIn(this, group);
        groups.add(isIn);
    }

    public void removeGroup(Group group) {
        for (Iterator<IsIn> iterator = groups.iterator();
             iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            IsIn isIn = iterator.next();

            if (isIn.getUser().equals(this) &&
                    isIn.getGroup().equals(group)) {
                iterator.remove();
                isIn.setUser(null);
                isIn.setGroup(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isIs_active() {
        return is_active;
    }

    public void setIs_active(boolean is_active) {
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }

    public String getNotificationType() {
        return notificationType;
    }

    public void setNotificationType(String notificationType) {
        this.notificationType = notificationType;
    }

    public String getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(String create_date) {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }
}
```

**Group**

```
package entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalIdCache;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
@NaturalIdCache
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "groupId")
    private int groupId;

    @Column(name = "groupName")
    private String groupName;

    @Column(name = "notificationMessage", nullable = false)
    private String notificationMessage;

    @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
    private String create_date;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    private User created_by;

    @Column(name = "isPrivate")
    private boolean isPrivate;

    public Group() { }

    public Group(String groupName, String notificationMessage, String create_date, boolean isPrivate) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.notificationMessage = notificationMessage;
        this.create_date = create_date;
        this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        Group group = (Group) o;
        return Objects.equals(groupId, group.getGroupId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(groupId); }

    public int getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public String getNotificationMessage() { return notificationMessage; }

    public void setNotificationMessage(String notificationMessage) {
        this.notificationMessage = notificationMessage;
    }

    public String getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(String create_date) {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }

    public boolean isPrivate() {
        return isPrivate;
    }

    public void setPrivate(boolean aPrivate) {
        isPrivate = aPrivate;
    }

    public User getCreated_by() {
        return created_by;
    }

    public void setCreated_by(User created_by) {
        this.created_by = created_by;
    }
}
```

**UserGroupId (Embeddable)**

```
package Embedded;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class UserGroupId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "userId")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "groupId")
    private int groupId;

    private UserGroupId() {}

    public UserGroupId(int userId, int groupId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        UserGroupId that = (UserGroupId) o;
        return Objects.equals(userId, that.userId) &&
                Objects.equals(groupId, that.groupId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, groupId);
    }
}
```

**IsIn**

```
package entity;

import Embedded.UserGroupId;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "isin")
public class IsIn {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("groupId")
    private Group group;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeId")
    private UserType typeId;

    @Column(name = "isBlocked", nullable = false)
    private boolean isBlocked;

    private IsIn() {}

    public IsIn(User user, Group group) {
        this.user = user;
        this.group = group;
        this.id = new UserGroupId(user.getUserId(), group.getGroupId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        IsIn that = (IsIn) o;
        return Objects.equals(user, that.user) &&
                Objects.equals(group, that.group);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(user, group);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public UserType getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public void setTypeId(UserType typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public boolean isBlocked() {
        return isBlocked;
    }

    public void setBlocked(boolean blocked) {
        isBlocked = blocked;
    }
}
```

**Privilege**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "privilege")
public class Privilege {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "privilegeId")
    private int privilegeId;

    @Column(name = "privilegeName", nullable = false)
    private String privilegeName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privilege")
    private Set<UserType> usertypes = new HashSet<>();

    public Privilege() {}

    public Privilege(String privilegeName) {
        this.privilegeName = privilegeName;
    }

    public int getPrivilegeId() {
        return privilegeId;
    }

    public void setPrivilegeId(int privilegeId) {
        this.privilegeId = privilegeId;
    }

    public String getPrivilegeName() {
        return privilegeName;
    }

    public void setPrivilegeName(String privilegeName) { this.privilegeName = privilegeName; }

    public Set<UserType> getUsertypes() { return usertypes; }
}
```

**UserType**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usertype")
public class UserType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "typeId")
    private int typeId;

    @Column(name = "typeName", nullable = false)
    private String typeName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "hasprivilege",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "typeId") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "privilegeId") }
    )
    Set<Privilege> privileges = new HashSet<>();

    public UserType() { }

    public UserType(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }

    public int getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public void setTypeId(int typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public String getTypeName() {
        return typeName;
    }

    public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }
}
```

**Notification**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "notification")
public class Notification {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "notificationId")
    private int notificationId;

    @Column(name = "notificationMessage", nullable = false)
    private String notificationMessage;

    @Column(name = "frequency", nullable = false)
    private String frequency;

    @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
    private String create_date;

    @Column(name = "update_date", nullable = false)
    private String update_date;

    public Notification() {}

    public Notification(String notificationMessage, String frequency, String create_date, String update_date) {
        this.notificationMessage = notificationMessage;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.create_date = create_date;
        this.update_date = update_date;
    }

    public int getNotificationId() {
        return notificationId;
    }

    public void setNotificationId(int notificationId) {
        this.notificationId = notificationId;
    }

    public String getNotificationMessage() {
        return notificationMessage;
    }

    public void setNotificationMessage(String notificationMessage) {
        this.notificationMessage = notificationMessage;
    }

    public String getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(String frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public String getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(String create_date) {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }

    public String getUpdate_date() {
        return update_date;
    }

    public void setUpdate_date(String update_date) {
        this.update_date = update_date;
    }
}
```

**Message**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "messageId")
    private String messageId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupId")
    private Group groupId;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private String create_date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "notificationId")
    private Notification notificationId;

    public Message() { }

    public Message(User userId, Group groupId, String message, String create_date, Notification notificationId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.message = message;
        this.create_date = create_date;
        this.notificationId = notificationId;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public User getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Group getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public Notification getNotificationId() {
        return notificationId;
    }
}
```

I've been looking on Stack for a solution on similar issues but the suggestions did not help in my case. I'm kinda stuck right now.

**Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank your for your time.**

Comment: Is your class `IsIn` in your hibernate config mapping? It should be there similar to this: `<mapping class="entity.IsIn"/>`

Comment: Is isin table available in database

Comment: @GarimaGupta yes, it is.